# Maintain scroll position of treeview

Tags: .net, winforms, treeview

How can I maintain the scroll position of a treeview control in .NET application? For example, I have a treeview control and go through a process of adding various nodes to it tacking them on to the bottom. During this process, I can scroll through the treeview and view different nodes. The problem is when the process completes, the treeview scrolls to the very bottom.

It appears that calling treenode.Expand() is what is throwing me off track here. When a parent node is expanded, it gets the focus.

Is there a way around this? If I'm looking at a specific node while the process is running, I don't want it to jump around on me when the process is done.

Comment: Related: *[How do I programmatically scroll TreeView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119995)*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think I figured it out:

1. Get the node at the top of the treeview.
2. Expand the parent node.
3. Make the node that was previously at the top visible.

> ```
> If treeNodeParent.IsExpanded = False Then
>     Dim currentNode As TreeNode = TreeViewHosts.GetNodeAt(0, 0)
>     treeNodeParent.Expand()
>     currentNode.EnsureVisible()
> End If
> ```

Is the a better way to do this?

Comment: This is the best way I have found, you just beat me to the answer as I was typing it up :)

Comment: Well I'll take that as confirmation for my answer then. Thanks lagerdalek.

Comment: The only better method I would suggest would be to replace `TreeViewHosts.GetNodeAt(0, 0)` with `TreeViewHosts.TopNode`

Then you may want to replace `currentNode.EnsureVisible()` with `TreeViewHosts.TopNode = currentNode`
But, they should effectively do the same thing.

Comment: Can someone post or explain which event handler this solution is for? Are you overriding the OnBeforeExpand() event?

Answer (score 29):

I'm not a VB guy but in C# I do it this way:

**Some Win32 native functions:**

```
[DllImport("user32.dll",  CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int GetScrollPos(IntPtr hWnd, int nBar);

[DllImport("user32.dll",  CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int SetScrollPos(IntPtr hWnd, int nBar, int nPos, bool bRedraw);

private const int SB_HORZ = 0x0;
private const int SB_VERT = 0x1;
```

**A method which returns a point for the current scroll position:**

```
private Point GetTreeViewScrollPos(TreeView treeView)
{
    return new Point(
        GetScrollPos(treeView.Handle, SB_HORZ), 
        GetScrollPos(treeView.Handle, SB_VERT));
}
```

**A method to set the scroll position:**

```
private void SetTreeViewScrollPos(TreeView treeView, Point scrollPosition)
{
    SetScrollPos(treeView.Handle, SB_HORZ, scrollPosition.X, true);
    SetScrollPos(treeView.Handle, SB_VERT, scrollPosition.Y, true); 
}
```

**Then when you update your tree, do the following:**

```
BeginUpdate();
Point ScrollPos = GetTreeViewScrollPos(treeMain);
// write your update code here
SetTreeViewScrollPos(treeMain, ScrollPos);
EndUpdate();
```

Comment: Just tested. Works good for me. I also added the functions as extension methods to TreeView :) ty

Comment: I tryed this code, but it affects only scroll bar on my tree, not contents.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it doesn't affect content"? Of course you need to set the previous selected again and with the above code your tree shouldn't change at all except for a very brief flicker. If your content changed between the refreshes, the scroll position will be slightly off, of course.

Comment: very nice, but why not define GetScrollPos using IntPtr also?

`public static extern int GetScrollPos(IntPtr hWnd, int nBar);`

Comment: To fix the but where content position doesn't change, use begin/end layout methods. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Another way you can preserve the scroll position without external functions is using the TopNode property of the tree...

TopNode gets or sets the first fully-visible tree node in the tree view control.

If you just want to expand a node and have it preserve the top node:

```
TreeNode topNode = m_Tree.TopNode;
treenode.Expand();
m_Tree.TopNode = topNode;
```

Otherwise, if you are rebuilding a tree (such as refreshing a file structure), you can use the following method...

Before Clearing the tree, store the full path to the top node:

```
string topNodePath = null;
TreeNode topNode = null;
if (m_Tree.TopNode != null)
{
    topNodePath = m_Tree.TopNode.FullPath;
}

m_Tree.Clear();
```

After adding a nodes, check its FullPath against the topNodePath:

```
nodes.Add(node)
if ((topNodePath != null) && (node.FullPath == topNodePath))
{
    topNode = node;
}
```

After adding all nodes, update the tree's TopNode property:

```
if (topNode != null)
{
    m_Tree.TopNode = topNode;
}
```

I use a similar technique for selected and expanded nodes.
SelectedNode works almost exactly as TopNode shown above.
For expanded nodes I use a recursive function to loop through the child nodes and add the path of expanded nodes to a list. Then expands them based on their path after the children have been added.

Of course, if you have a lot of sibling nodes with the same name, this might not work as well :-)

Comment: Sure. All fixed :-)

Comment: you can also use topNode.EnsureVisible() instead of setting the tree top node

Comment: Just used TopNode, works fine by just looking for the tree node with the same contents (i.e. Tag in my case) again. Note to people thinking EnsureVisible works as well: It doesn't, because it does not make sure that the node is at the top, it just makes sure it is *somewhere* in the visible area, so you may still have scrolling to (for the user) random nodes.

Answer (score 3):

I found it's best to wrap the `SetTreeViewScrollPosition(point)` with a `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate`...

```
private void treeViewXml1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    Point point = treeViewXml1.GetTreeViewScrollPosition();

    treeViewXml2.BeginUpdate();
    treeViewXml2.SetTreeViewScrollPosition(point);
    treeViewXml2.EndUpdate();
}

private void treeViewXml2_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    Point point = treeViewXml2.GetTreeViewScrollPosition();

    treeViewXml1.BeginUpdate();
    treeViewXml1.SetTreeViewScrollPosition(point);
    treeViewXml1.EndUpdate();
}
```

Comment: +1 The `BeginUpdate()` and `EndUpdate()` did the trick for me!

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem where the scroll itself updated, but the contents of the treeview didn't get scrolled. This was easily fixed by adding `BeginUpdate()` and `EndUpdate()` around `SetScrollPos()`.

```
this.hierarchyTreeView.BeginUpdate();
SetScrollPos(this.hierarchyTreeView.Handle, SB_VERT, 5, true);
this.hierarchyTreeView.EndUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myTreeView.Nodes[0].EnsureVisible();
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's always better to provide a short description for a sample code to improve the post accuracy :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a revision of the beautiful response from Stefan Koell, as a TreeViewExtension:
(complete solution)

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Media;

public static class TreeViewExtension
{
    #region Constants

    private const int ScrollBarHorizontal = 0x0;

    private const int ScrollBarVertical = 0x1;

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods and Operators

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int GetScrollPos(int hWnd, int nBar);

    public static Point ScrollPosition(this TreeView treeView)
    {
        return new Point(
            GetScrollPos((int)treeView.Handle(), ScrollBarHorizontal), 
            GetScrollPos((int)treeView.Handle(), ScrollBarVertical));
    }

    public static void ScrollTo(this TreeView treeView, Point scrollPosition)
    {
        SetScrollPos(treeView.Handle(), ScrollBarHorizontal, (int)scrollPosition.X, true);
        SetScrollPos(treeView.Handle(), ScrollBarVertical, (int)scrollPosition.Y, true);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SetScrollPos(IntPtr hWnd, int nBar, int nPos, bool bRedraw);

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    private static IntPtr Handle(this Visual treeView)
    {
        var handle = IntPtr.Zero;
        var hwndSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(treeView) as HwndSource;
        if (hwndSource != null)
        {
            handle = hwndSource.Handle;
        }

        return handle;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Perhaps it simplifies your work ;-)

Comment: The signature on `GetScrollPos` should be changed to `(IntPtr, int)`, otherwise the program will crash on 64-bit windows.

Comment: private static IntPtr Handle(this Visual treeView) {...} can be removed treeView.Handle is already an IntPtr that can be used.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine. Save the TopNode and restore after:

```
this.treeView.BeginUpdate();
TreeNode topNode = this.treeView.TopNode;

// your code
this.treeView.Sort();
this.treeView.SelectedNode = auxNode;

this.treeView.TopNode = topNode;
this.treeView.EndUpdate();
```

Answer (score -3):

The best thing is to use UpdatePanel and nest your treeview tags inside it. For example,

```
<asp:UpdatePanel id="UpdatePanel">
     <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:TreeView id="TreeView">

         </asp:TreeView>
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

It worked for me, and I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Please note that this is a **Winforms** question, not an ASP.NET question. [Winforms doesn't have an UpdatePanel](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/28a7bc70-7171-4316-b281-d4e078749932/update-panel-equivalent-in-windows-forms-application-cnet?forum=csharpgeneral).