# How do I programmatically scroll TreeView?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I need to scroll **TreeView** (*Windows Forms*) from **TOP** to **BOTTOM**...

I should clarify that I have **two TreeViews**... If the first was scrolled by the user, the second treeView must be automatically scrolled. I don't know what node is selected...

How can I do this?

Comment: Related: [Maintain scroll position of treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332788/maintain-scroll-position-of-treeview)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

For top node:

```
TreeView.Nodes[0].EnsureVisible();
```

For bottom node:

```
TreeView.Nodes[TreeView.Nodes.Count-1].EnsureVisible();
```

Comment: Please, review my question (previously I didn't fully describe problem)... it's been corrected.. thanks..

Comment: Do the treeview have the same nodes in each?

Comment: I'm writing Comparer (similar as Beyound Compare)... but the body is the tree, not a text...

Comment: I have an idea.... I can take first visible node in the first tree, get it index, and invoke EnsureVisible() for node from second tree with same index... it seems this should be solution...

Comment: ok, well you could check the selected node index in the first tree, check if the index exists in the second tree, select the node based on the index and call ensurevisible?

Comment: The TopNode property doesn't necessarily return the first node of the tree-- it returns the first visible node.

Comment: @EricLaw-MSFT- Thanks, I didnt realise that, what would you suggest instead? would TreeView.Nodes[0].EnsureVisble work?

Comment: @WraithNath - Yes, Nodes[0] is what you want.

Comment: Does `Ensurevisible` collapse nodes? If so how can I prevent that?

Comment: @beppe9000 - I dont think so, but perhaps you could follow up the .EnsureVisible() with .Expand() / .ExpandAll()?

Comment: @WraithNath lol i'm here because expand all scrolls the control to the bottom