# Scrolling TreeView from code-behind WinForms

Tags: .net, winforms, scroll, treeview

I'm writing an application in winForms (C#) which will be Touch-able. And I have problem with scrolling a TreeView, I know how to catch when user want to scroll content of TreeView by finger, but I don't know how to force TreeView to scroll from code-behind.

Comment: Ok, I find solution, if someone will have the same problem here is how to solve this:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332788/maintain-scroll-position-of-treeview)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintain scroll position of treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332788/maintain-scroll-position-of-treeview)