# Speed up scrolling in winforms treeView

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, treeview

I need to speed up vertical scrolling while draging item in treeView in winforms project. I am not very familiar with winforms. Is this possible with treeView? Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a combination of the TreeView's ItemDrag event and this answer, [Maintain scroll position of treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332788/maintain-scroll-position-of-treeview), to do what you are attempting to do.